# How to change the color of thumb switch react js

Tags: reactjs

I have a switch that I would like to change the color of the circle to a dark gray. I've looked on the internet but I can't quite understand how to use the css rules that exist in the component documentation. Can anybody help me!? Here is my code:

```
const ThemeToggle = () => {

    const { theme, setTheme } = useContext(ThemeContext);
    const handleThemeToggle = () => {
        setTheme(theme === 'light' ? 'dark' : 'light');

        if (theme === 'light') {
            document.body.classList.add('darkBackground');
        } else {
            document.body.classList.remove('darkBackground');
        }
    };



    return <div>
        <Switch
            uncheckedIcon={false}
            checkedIcon={false}
            onColor={'#eee'}
            onChange={handleThemeToggle}
            checked={theme === 'light'}

        />
    </div>
}

export default ThemeToggle;
```

Component Documentation: https://mui.com/material-ui/api/switch/

I use this switch to change the mode. So while in light mode the thumb would be grayed out. In dark mode, the thumbnail would be white

**ThemeContext:

```
export const ThemeContext = React.createContext({} as IThemeContext);

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const storedTheme = localStorage.getItem("darkTheme");
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState(storedTheme);


  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("darkTheme", theme);
  })

  return (

    <ThemeContext.Provider value={{ theme, setTheme }}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <BrowserRouter>
        <GlobalStyle />
        <AppRouter />
      </BrowserRouter>

    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Comment: can you share the context?

Comment: @olscode I edited the question and added themecontext

Comment: i have edited my answer too with your context, can you have a look?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I created the following codesandbox where you can see how I change the colour of the Switch component with CSS global class this website: https://mui.com/material-ui/api/switch/#css provides + your case that you just want it when its darkBackground:

```
.darkBackground {
  background-color: #404042;
  color: gray;
}

.light {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
}

.MuiSwitch-switchBase .MuiSwitch-thumb {
  color: purple;
}

.MuiSwitch-switchBase + .MuiSwitch-track {
  background-color: purple;
}

.darkBackground .MuiSwitch-switchBase.Mui-checked .MuiSwitch-thumb {
  color: white;
}

.darkBackground .MuiSwitch-switchBase.Mui-checked + .MuiSwitch-track {
  background-color: white;
}
```

I wasn't able to change the context that's why i asked you if you could share it but if you make the context work in this demo it should work as you expect:

**DEMO:**

https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-shannon-36bl1m?file=/src/styles.css

Comment: first, thank you so much for your help! I just couldn't apply. I saw in the documentation that to change just the color thumb, I would have to put:  .MuiSwitch-thumb I did it, but I couldn't.

Comment: you re right i have edited my answer right now can you have a look into the css file?

Answer (score 0):

Try to overwrite this class:

```
.MuiSwitch-colorSecondary.Mui-checked {
  color: green; // any color you want
}
```

Example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-switch-forked-2plbik?file=/src/components/SwitchContainer.jsx

Comment: I did that and nothing changes :(